# Too complex password for a FTP bash script?

Tags: bash, ftp, scripting, password

I've read several questions related to this matter, but none of them seems to have a valid answer to my problem. I just need to write a simple bash script to get a couple of files via an FTP connection.

The normal script was this

```
#!/bin/bash
username="myFTPusername"
password="myFTPpass"
ftp -in hostname <<EOF
quote USER $username
quote PASS $password
lcd mylocaldirectory
cd FTPfolder
get filename
bye
EOF
```

And I've also tried this command, seen [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/138151/run-ftp-session-from-bash-script)

```
wget -O filename ftp://user:pass@hostname/filename
```

But none of them work. Weid enough, I can access without problems without the script, and my user and password work fine. But when I try to connect via the script or the wget command, I get a "login incorrect".

Is there some kind of limitation on the password format? It has different characters, **and one of them is a "$"**. My only guess is that that dollar sign is the problem in the script. Any ideas to solve it? What if I coulnd't change that FTP pass?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using wget (or curl) is probably your best bet.  If your password contains shell metacharacters (like '$'), you'll need to quote it on the command line.  For example:

```
wget -O filename 'ftp://user:pass@hostname/filename'
```

Using single quotes inhibits the expansion of '$' inside the quoted string.

Comment: That was the answer ;) Good job larsks, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than store the authentication details in the script, try putting them in [~/.netrc](http://linux.die.net/man/5/netrc), this should get around any problems with the shell expanding the $ character in your password.

Comment: Mmm thanks for the suggestion. The wget solution is simpler and works, but I'll try yours as well. Thanks!